# Change the Color of Status Bar TEXT and icon in API 30

Tags: java, android, statusbar, android-statusbar

I want the **icons and text** on the StatusBar to be black. I have tried in various ways, but obviously it is a problem because API 30 does not respond to the already existing solutions I found on the net. Can anyone give specific instructions on how to **change the color of icons and text**. Please note that I am using `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar`
I ask for your help.

This is what it should look like:

[image]

My style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark" targetApi="23">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="customBackgroundColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="customPrimaryTextColor">#000000</item>

</style>
```

This code changes the background color of the StatusBar, but I needs to change the color of the text and icons on the StatusBar.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_color));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

As per documentation: you need to use `WindowInsetsController` to set [`setAppearanceLightStatusBars`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/WindowInsetsControllerCompat#setAppearanceLightStatusBars(boolean)) which changes the foreground color of the status bars (icons & text):

```
new WindowInsetsControllerCompat(getWindow(), 
        getWindow().getDecorView()).setAppearanceLightStatusBars(true);
```

**UPDATE**

No need to the below, also they have deprecated APIs:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    Window window = this.getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    
}
```

To make the status bar light & icons/text dark on API Level 30:

**Method 1:** Programmatically:

```
new WindowInsetsControllerCompat(getWindow(), 
                getWindow().getDecorView()).setAppearanceLightStatusBars(true);
getWindow().setStatusBarColor( ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.primary_color, null)); // Or Color.WHITE make it white
```

**Method 2:** In themes.xml:

add this in your app's theme:

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_color</item>
```

Comment: I put this in `onCreate` but nothing happened! :(

Comment: Let me double check it tonight pls

Comment: @Dejo Just updated the answer; give the XML a try; but both worked with me on a physical device.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked. I have tested on android 8.0 and above.